# 503 service unavailable debugging PHP files

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debugging, 503-error

I have a web server with apache 2.0 installed. It comes with Zend Server install pack.
When I’m trying to debug my php files apache serves a blank page with 503 service unavailable.
Of course slow server-side code is tying up Apache requests for far too long, but I need it to wait, until my debugging comes to end. 
How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is it timing out before displaying the error, or is the 503 error coming up right away?  Try adding a set_time_limit() command at the beginning of your script  to see if that gives it time to finish.  I think the default timeout is only 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. 
When I call to page from a browser it launches ZendStudio debugging my PHP script (request redirects Zend Debugger module). I debug through my script and if I finish debugging in 120 seconds, I normally return to browser. When it takes more than 120 seconds browser displays 503 503 service unavailable and I can't return to page output. I have even forced 'max_execution_time = 300' 'max_input_time = 600' in php.ini and 'TimeOut = 500' in httpd.conf.
No matter it is Opera, IE of Firefox. 
Spent two days googling it, no right answer till now.

Sergey.

Comment: @Ryan Hamilton: The right command to remove timeout is `set_time_limit(0);`